# how to put different type of data types in a Array dynamic in C

Tags: c

i try to store name and age in a dynamic array 
when we have a different type of data , int , and Char that we dont know the size in the start how to use a dynamic array to store the  2 types

```
typedef struct personne{
char nom ;
int age ;

}personne;

struct personne saisie_personne_suivante(struct personne* x){


scanf("%s",&x->nom);


scanf("%d",&x->age);


return *x;
}

int main(void){


personne *ali;
ali = malloc(sizeof(char*));
saisie_personne_suivante(ali);

printf("\n %d ",ali->age);


printf("\n %s",&ali->nom);
return 0;
}
```

Why i dont sucess ?

Comment: I strongly advise you to get your hands on a book on C or a decent tutorial at least.

Comment: What you're doing is allocating space equal to size of a pointer to char, (which is either 32 or 64bits wide, depending on your OS).

What you probably want to do is allocate space equal to size of your struct (5 bytes most likely), that is `sizeof(struct personne)`

Answer (score 0):

i think we cant store two types of data at a time in array.If we do so we need to allocate half of memory to char and half to integers provided you should give some size of array.
=>in your program at this line [ali = malloc(sizeof(char*))] you are passsing address of only char not of variable.If you want to store both values just pass address of both int and char.

Answer (score 0):

`ali` is a pointer to a struct of size `sizeof(char) + sizeof(int)` which may vary between architectures.

For the time being, let's assume it's 5 bytes (which it probably is on your PC).

What you're doing, is allocate space equal to size of a `pointer to char`, (which is either 32 or 64bits wide, depending on your OS).

What you probably want to do is allocate space equal to size of your struct (5 bytes), that is:

```
ali = malloc(sizeof(personne));
```

Note the lack of *, since you want actual memory for a struct and not a pointer pointing to such a location.

By the way, you wouldn't want to write: `malloc(sizeof(char))` either, since that would be just one byte needed for your struct.

I **strongly advise** you to get your hands on **a book on C** or a decent tutorial at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

personne *ali;
ali = (struct personne *)malloc(sizeof(personne));

saisie_personne_suivante(ali);

printf("\n %d ", ali->age);

printf("\n %c", ali->nom);
return 0;
```

}

There is not enough memory for struct personne, so you need to malloc sizeof(personne) memory. nom is not a pointer,it's a char variable,when you print it, use printf("%c",ali->nom);

Answer (score 0):

I can concur with the commenters who recommended a good book/tutorial to get started but nevertheless: here is your repaired code, with a bit of comment.

```
// printf(), fprintf(), and puts()
#include <stdio.h>
// exit(), malloc(), and scanf()
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PERSONNE_ERROR   0
#define PERSONNE_OK      1

typedef struct personne {
  // fixed width for 49 characters and the trailing NUL
  char nom[50];
  int age;
} personne;

int saisie_personne_suivante(struct personne *x)
{
  // For the returns of the scanf()s.
  // Because you always check the returns if available
  // (well, actually: the returns of printf() et al. rarely get checked)
  // preset it to a value meant to say "OK"
  int res = PERSONNE_OK;
  // UX: let the users know what they are supposed to do.
  puts("Your name, please");
  // we have a fixed maximum size of name and we can set it here within scanf()
  // scanf() returns the number of elements it parsed, *not* the number of characters

  // sacnf() needs a pointer to the memory it is expected to put the value into.
  // x->nom is already a pointer to a char array, no need to use "&"
  if ((res = scanf("%49s", x->nom)) != 1) {
    // we can return immediatly here.
    // If we would need to cleanup (free memory, for example) we would
    // set res to PERSONNE_ERROR and use a goto to jump at the place
    // where all the cleanup happens. But that should be done if the clean-up
    // is always the same (or could be sorted) and you need such cleanups
    // more than just two or three times.
    return PERSONNE_ERROR;
  }

  puts("Your age, too, if you don't mind.");
  // x->age is not a pointer to an int, hence we need to prefix "&"
  if ((res = scanf("%d", &x->age)) != 1) {
    return PERSONNE_ERROR;
  }
  return res;
}

int main(void)
{
  personne *ali;
  int res;

  // reserve momory for the struct
  ali = malloc(sizeof(personne));
  // call function that fills the struct and check the return
  if ((res = saisie_personne_suivante(ali)) != PERSONNE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something went wrong with saisie_personne_suivante()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // print the content of struct personne
  // you can feed printf() directly, no need to find the pointer to the memory
  // holding the int
  printf("Age:  %d\n", ali->age);
  // To print strings it needs to know the start of the string whcih needs to be
  // a pointer and ali->nom is a pointer to the start of the string
  printf("Name: %s\n", ali->nom);
  // free allocated memory (not really necessary at the end of the
  // program but it's deemed good style and because it costs us nothing
  // we cannot find a good reason to skip it)
  free(ali);
  // exit with a value that tells the OS that this programm ended without an error
  // It shoudl be 0 (zero) which it almost always is.
  // *Almost* always
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But really: go and get some beginners book/tutorial. I cannot give you a recommendation because I don't know about any good ones in your native language (sometimes the english version is good but the translation lacks a lot).

Comment: if we want 3 Personne ? personne saisie_clavier(personne *c,int num){
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<num;i++){
 
 scanf("%s",c->nom);
 scanf("%d",&c->age);
 
 }
 return *c;
 }

Comment: @Cod3r the loop is a good start but you'll need one struct for every person and store these structs somewhere, too. One possible way is to use a so called linked list, described here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/560/linked-lists#t=20161009201717057921 but Google might be a bit more useful to find information about linked lists in C.